# make a voice sound signal play faster

Tags: signal-analysis, sound, voice

Suppose $x(t)$ is a signal containing a voice. How can one derive a signal playing the same voice faster.

I tried $x(t+\lfloor{100t\rfloor}/100)$ to double the speed; But it adds a buzz sound. Is there a better formula?

Clearly $x(2t)$ changes the voice. I want to change just the speed.

Comment: See other posts that mention “phase vocoder”; changes the speed without changing the pitch or vice versa

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the sampling rate, instead of the signal $x(nT_s) = x(n/F_s)$, you can play it at say $\frac{11}{10}F_s, \frac{12}{10}F_s, \text{or}\ 2F_s$. So you have:
\begin{align}
x\left(\frac{n}{\frac{11}{10}F_s}\right) &=x\left(\frac{10n}{11F_s}\right) = x\left(n\frac{10}{11}T_s\right)\\
x\left(\frac{n}{\frac{12}{10}F_s}\right) &=x\left(\frac{10 n}{12F_s}\right) = x\left(n\frac{10}{12}T_s\right)\\
x\left(\frac{n}{2F_s}\right) &=x\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{n}{F_s}\right) = x\left(n\frac{1}{2}T_s\right) 
\end{align}
In MATLAB for instance, you can try the code below.

```
clear all

load handel.mat
sound(y, Fs) % original 
sound(y, 1.1*Fs) % at 1.1*Fs
sound(y, 1.2*Fs) % at 1.2*Fs
sound(y, 2*Fs) % at twice Fs
```

Gradually increasing the frequency to hear the changes in speed. You can try even higher, like 4 times, to hear the differences. The `handel.mat` file should be in there by default.

**EDIT:**

You $x(t)$ in your program is samples of the signal for a certain time duration, check how many samples you have per second (i.e. the sampling rate or frequency $F_s$), and $T_s = 1/F_s$. And $x(t) = x(nT_s) = x(n/F_s)$ with $n = 0, \ldots, N-1$ where $N$ is the number of samples. Taking a higher $F_s$ corresponds to taking smaller $T_s$.

Comment: Thanks. But I have C# program which gets $x(t)$ as a continuous function and uses it to produce a wave file. I have the sampling machine code but I prefer to change $x(t)$ itself. Can you recommend a change in $x(t)$?

Comment: @nano please see my edit.

Comment: Isn't it the same as sampling $x(at)$ where $a$ is a constant? The problem with this is that the pitch changes.

Comment: @nano search DSP.SE for [pitch shift](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22pitch+shift%22) or [associated techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_shift) (like "time stretching"). This is a frequent question on this board and you can find some useful stuff in addition to the method that Gilles is suggesting to you here.